# How do I loop through a graphic of bricks ive created?

Tags: java, loops, graphics

The problem I'm having is getting my program to loop through the bricks that I have created for my Breakout game.

Ive tried a few different ways by calling the createBrick() method but isn't working. Is someone able to tell me if im on the right track or not? This is my code below for my BreakoutPanel class.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BreakoutPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

private boolean gameRunning = true;
private int livesLeft = 3;
private String screenMessage = "";
private Ball ball;
private Paddle paddle;
private Brick[] bricks;
private int xVelocity;

public BreakoutPanel(Breakout game) {

    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);

    Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);
    timer.start();

    ball = new Ball();                                                              // Creates ball object with appropriate variable
    paddle = new Paddle();                                                          // Creates paddle object with appropriate variable
    bricks = new Brick [Settings.TOTAL_BRICKS];                                     // Creates brick array

    createBricks(null);                                                             // Call the createBricks() method

}
private void createBricks(Graphics g) {
    int counter = 0;
    int x_space = 0;
    int y_space = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            bricks[counter] = new Brick((x * Settings.BRICK_WIDTH) + Settings.BRICK_HORI_PADDING + x_space, (y * Settings.BRICK_HEIGHT) + Settings.BRICK_VERT_PADDING + y_space);
            counter++;
            y_space++;
        }
        x_space++;
        y_space = 0;
    }
}
private void paintBricks(Graphics g) {
    paintComponent(g);
    // TODO: Loop through the bricks and call the paint() method

    paint(g);
}
```

The result im needing is for my program to print out my bricks but at the moment cant figure out how to loop through my bricks. Sorry if this is a bad question ive been looking at google and youtube but can only find versions the program where they have a physical picture of a brick and haven't actually created it themselves. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You mean like `for(Brick b : bricks)`?

Answer (score 0):

As I see 
private Brick[] bricks; I assume you just want to loop in an array (named bricks) of class Brick.

Then simple :

```
for (int i=0;i< bricks.length;i++)
{

    //do things with bricks[i] as example bricks[i].draw() or myMethod(bricks[i]); ...
}
```

Comment: If you use `i < bricks.length - 1`, you will always skip the last element. Don't think that's intended.